# Adding rows dynamically to a pageblocktable even if the values in the required fields for existing rows are blank

Tags: visualforce

I have a pageblock table where I have a pageblockbutton to add rows. I want to be able to add more rows even if the required fields of existing rows are not filled, i.e., without being shown Error: You must enter a value. Should I be using jQuery?

Comment: Please update your code. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

There is a tag on commandButton and commandLink called `immediate` http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_commandButton.htm

Setting this to true on your `addRow` button should bypass the page validation.

Note: this will not bypass database validations.